# Porting socket interface from Qt to STD library

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, std, nonblocking

I am trying to port a Qt socket interface to STD library socket interface. I'm building a wrapper similar to my Qt wrapper in STD.

The QTcpSocket interface was very convenient in that it offered signals such as:

```
connect(m_pSocket, SIGNAL(connected()),    this, SLOT(onConnected()));
connect(m_pSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(onDisconnected()));
connect(m_pSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),    this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
```

Unfortunately STD does not provide these so my main question is regarding reading data. The way I did it in Qt was connect the QTcpSocket readyRead signal to a function I wrote in the wrapper:

```
void MyClass::onReadyRead()
{
    // Input buffer is empty so new message
    bool isNewMsg = m_inBuffer.isEmpty();

    // Read available data in socket into input buffer
    m_mutex.lock();
    while (m_pSocket->bytesAvailable() > 0)
    {
        m_inBuffer.append(m_pSocket->readAll());
    }
    m_mutex.unlock();

    // If new message extract full receive length
    if (isNewMsg)
    {
        const char* inBuf = (const char *) m_inBuffer.data();

        m_expRcvLen = atoi((char *)inBuf) + SOCKET_HEADER_LENGTH;
    }

    int currRcvLen = m_inBuffer.size();
    if (currRcvLen < m_expRcvLen)
    {
        // Expecting more packets
        return;
    }

    // Reset for next message
    m_expRcvLen = 0;

    // Emit signal data read form socket
    emit dataReceived(m_inBuffer);
}
```

I guess my question is how can I get the same behavior in STD library and possibly libsigc++ to implement:

- Non-Blocking Socket
- Notification when data is available

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are looking for will require you to write your own executor either using poll on unix or IoCompletion ports on windows. Not a trivial exercise.

The `asio` library which is part of boost has its own executor. It also provides `async_connect` and `async_read` both that callbacks which can use similar functions to the ones you provide as Qt slots.